# Create executable expression calling generic method

Tags: c#, .net-core, akka.net

Ok so let's assume I have this kind of class hierarchy:

```cs
/// In 3rd party library 
public class WidgetBase
{
    protected void Register<THandler>(Action<THandler> handler) { /* do something */ }
}

public record Message1();
public record Message2();

public sealed class MyWidget : Base
{
    public MyClass()
    {      
        RegisterHandlers(this);
    }

    [Handler]
    private void Handle(Message1 msg) {}
    
    [Handler]
    private void Handle(Message2 msg) {}
}

public static class Ext
{
    // Would prefer extension or normal static method
    // and not impose inheritance by putting this
    // in an intermediatery base class.
    public static void RegisterHandlers<T>(this T t)
    {
        // Discovers methods with 'Handler' attribute and calls t.Register()
    }
}
```

So the objective is to implement `RegisterHandlers` which would introspect over the object's methods and then produce an executable `Expression` which calls the base classes register method. Think on the lines of Asp.Net Core Controller handlers.

I just can't figure out how to do this. The point of the expression would be to be more performant though even a pure reflection based solution would be ok.

I can discover the methods and even produce an expression like `t => this.Handle(t)` but can't understand how the call to the generic base class method is done without the type.

There are a lot of similar questions in SO but couldn't find exact solution.

[Edit]
Made the example more clear.

Comment: Are `SomeType1` and `SomeType2` derived from `Base`?

Comment: "I can discover the methods and even produce an expression" can you post this code?

Comment: Well your `Register` method is protected, so there's no way to call it from a compiled expression...

Comment: @canton7 Since it has to be specialized anyway, it's still going to need to be pulled by reflection. At that point `protected` is just a guideline.

Comment: If either of our answers are helpful, we'd appreciate if you'd let us know. If there's anything you don't get we're happy to explain.

Comment: Thanks for the samples. I will try the code out and mark one accepted if it works.

They look promising. The part I was missing is how to generate the generic call from the type info.

Comment: IMHO, step 1) let C# do it and decompile it (https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAExAagD4AEBMBGAsAKHQAYACdbAOgBlYBHCgUQA8AHAJwFMBnLqAexhcA3AXQBmMphIBZEgG8AvqIlYSAYXkES2kuz4AXDgGNDCMgBYSAJQ4BzKF0NsAPABUAEhBgIANhzYAfAAU5Jhunt5+gSQAFl6+/gCU8kr4OmQqlhEJQbJgiYpaOuIWMkHJckXp2szs3LwCzqHOagEBJJz2jv4kALwkQUbJve1GFDZdTs7SwWPZfokiaTqpCkA)

Comment: If your handlers were static, then you can cache a static delegate, reducing the runtime cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* do something like:

```
public static void RegisterHandlers<T>(T t) where T : Base
{
    var methods = typeof(T).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<HandlerAttribute>() != null);
    var registerMethod = typeof(Base).GetMethod("Register", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    
    var blockItems = new List<Expression>();
    foreach (var method in methods)
    {
        if (method.IsGenericMethod || method.GetParameters().Length != 1 || method.ReturnType != typeof(void))
            throw new Exception($"Invalid method signature for method {method}");
        
        // The type of the Handle method's parameter (e.g. SomeType1 or SomeType2)
        var parameterType = method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
        
        // MethodInfo for e.g. the Register<SomeType1> method
        var typedRegisterMethod = registerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(parameterType);
        
        // The type of delegate we'll pass to Register, e.g. Action<SomeType1>
        var delegateType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(parameterType);
        
        // Construct the x => Handle(x) delegate
        var delegateParameter = Expression.Parameter(parameterType);
        var delegateConstruction = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(t), method, delegateParameter), delegateParameter);
        
        // Construct the Register(delegate) call
        var methodCall = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(t), typedRegisterMethod, new[] { delegateConstruction });
        
        // Add this to the list of expressions we'll put in our block
        blockItems.Add(methodCall);
    }
    
    var compiled = Expression.Lambda<Action>(Expression.Block(blockItems)).Compile();
    compiled();
}
```

[See it on dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EFDnOW).

Note that there's no particular advantage to doing this, over just using reflection. You're not caching the generated `compiled` or `blockItems`, which is where the savings in using compiled expressions for this sort of thing come from.

---

You could extend it slightly however, and add in such a cache:

```
private static class Cache<T> where T : Base
{
    public static readonly Action<T> Instance = CreateInstance();
    
    private static Action<T> CreateInstance()
    {
        var methods = typeof(T).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<HandlerAttribute>() != null);
        var registerMethod = typeof(Base).GetMethod("Register", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        var instanceParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        var blockItems = new List<Expression>();
        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            if (method.IsGenericMethod || method.GetParameters().Length != 1 || method.ReturnType != typeof(void))
                throw new Exception($"Invalid method signature for method {method}");

            // The type of the Handle method's parameter (e.g. SomeType1 or SomeType2)
            var parameterType = method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;

            // MethodInfo for e.g. the Register<SomeType1> method
            var typedRegisterMethod = registerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(parameterType);

            // The type of delegate we'll pass to Register, e.g. Action<SomeType1>
            var delegateType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(parameterType);

            // Construct the x => Handle(x) delegate
            var delegateParameter = Expression.Parameter(parameterType);
            var delegateConstruction = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, Expression.Call(instanceParameter, method, delegateParameter), delegateParameter);

            // Construct the Register(delegate) call
            var methodCall = Expression.Call(instanceParameter, typedRegisterMethod, new[] { delegateConstruction });

            // Add this to the list of expressions we'll put in our block
            blockItems.Add(methodCall);
        }

        var compiled = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(Expression.Block(blockItems), instanceParameter).Compile();
        return compiled;
    }
}

public static void RegisterHandlers<T>(T t) where T : Base
{
    Cache<T>.Instance(t);
}
```

[See it on dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wceEak).

Note how we're now taking the `T` instance as a parameter, and this lets us cache the generated `Action<T>`.

Comment: OK, your solution is more fun than mine. System.Linq.Expressions is an interesting namespace to play around with.

Comment: I probably should've been more clear about the performance considerations. It's ok if the registering is a bit slowish. It would be called in the class constructor. How ever the delegate/action that is registered should have same performance as a normal action as it will be executed a lot.

The context is Akka.Net where you register the message handlers. I was looking into a way to remove some boilerplate and to use similar approach as Asp.Net Core does.

Comment: About the caching. I'm not sure that code is correct. You would need to cache per instance right since the generated delegates are bound to a specific object, which in this case defeats the point. I guess you could implement a partial cache for the discovery part and then do the final binding and compile when needed.

Comment: @MarkkuL No need to use expressions then: a delegate created using reflection is going to be just as fast as one created by a compiled expression. Re the caching, there's one compiled expression per *type*, and it takes the *instance* as a parameter: it's effectively just the method `void E(MyWidget w) { w.Register(Message1 msg => w.Handle(msg); w.Register(Message2 msg => w.Handle(msg)); }`. Notice how the method `E` is specialised to the type `MyWidget`, but takes the exact widget `w` as a parameter?

Comment: I was able to get this version to work with slight modifications. The actual "register" method has a deglaration `protected void Receive<T>(Action<T> handler, Predicate<T> shouldHandle = null)` so I had to provide the predicate argument also:
```c#
var nullPred = 
                    Expression.Convert(
                        Expression.Constant(null),
                        typeof(Predicate<>).MakeGenericType(messageType));
```

Comment: The key part for me was this:

```c#
// The type of delegate we'll pass to Register, e.g. Action<MsgType1>
                var delegateType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(messageType);
```

Though I'm not sure how useful this is at the end since for Akka.Net actors it works only for a single skenario and not for instance with `Become()` or `FSM`.

It was a good learning experience.

One way one could achieve similar results is with the new code generators, by making the Widget class as partial and generating the code. This does not require reflection naturally.

Comment: Note that `Expression.Constant` has an overload which takes a `Type`, so you could write `Expression.Constant(null, typeof....)`, rather than adding in the `Expression.Convert`

Comment: Yep, source generators are another way to tackle this. I'm not sure I'd bother for this case: the overhead with getting one written is quite a bit higher, and if you don't care about the reflection cost, the reflection approach is going to be a lot more self-contained and easier to maintain

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with the code you've got so far, mostly around the extension method not being correctly defined. Also when you're writing code that uses several different generics that aren't all going to accept the same type, it helps to give the type parameters more descriptive names than `T`.

The other point is that your extension probably should go into the base class as a protected method. Your real use case may differ enough from the above to warrant an extension form, but give some thought to whether you really need it that way. Is the extension tightly coupled to the `Base` class? If so, it's not really a good choice for an extension unless the base class is outside of your control. Even then a proxy base class might be a better option.

Anyway, on to the direct solution: reflection.

The basic flow will be something like this:

- Get the generic method template for the `Register<>` method.
- For each method in the derived class that has the `Handler` attribute:

  - Specialize the `Register<>` method with the correct parameter type.
  - Create a correctly typed delegate to invoke the method on the current instance.
  - Call the specialized method with the delegate as a parameter.
- Profit.

(OK, I'm just assuming that last bit.)

The most interesting part is getting a "correctly typed delegate" from the method. While `MethodInfo` contains a `CreateDelegate` method, you have to pass in the correctly specialized `Action<T>` type. Fortunately the parameter type for your specialized `Register<>` method is exactly what we want here.

Let's try a simple implementation:

```
static class Ext
{
    public static void RegisterHandlers<T>(this T instance)
    {
        // Get the generic method template for `Register<T>`
        var registerTemplate = typeof(T).GetMethod("Register", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        
        // Locate all handler methods
        var handlerQuery = 
            from m in typeof(T).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)
            where m.ReturnType == typeof(void) && m.GetCustomAttribute<HandlerAttribute>() != null
            let parms = m.GetParameters()
            where parms.Length == 1
            select (m, parms[0].ParameterType);
        
        foreach (var (handler, parmType) in handlerQuery)
        {
            // Specialize the Register<> method
            var registerMethod = registerTemplate.MakeGenericMethod(parmType);
            
            // Create Action<T> delegate for method
            var actionType = registerMethod.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
            object action = handler.CreateDelegate(actionType, instance);
            
            // Call the specialized Register<> method
            registerMethod.Invoke(instance, new[] { action });
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to add proper error handling and so on, but the that's the basic idea.

While it works in this specific case, I've used a very simple `GetMethod` call to get the generic method template. Validating that you have the correct method - that it's a generic method template (hint: `IsGenericMethodDefinition`) and that the parameter is the right type - is a little more difficult. The common issues can be addressed this way:

```
    var registerTemplate = 
    (
        from m in typeof(T).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)
        where m.Name == "Register" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition
        let args = m.GetGenericArguments()
        where args.Length == 1
        let actionTemplate = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(args[0])
        let parms = m.GetParameters()
        where parms.Length == 1 && parms[0].ParameterType == actionTemplate
        select m
    ).FirstOrDefault();
    if (registerTemplate is null)
        return;
```

That will at least save you from embarrassing crashes in the case of an incompatible `Register` method being defined, or an ambiguous match, or... etc.

---

As fun as that was, I'd give some serious though to finding a non-reflection method where you can. Reflection can be a bit messy and is quite slow. If you can't eliminate the reflection, at least try to minimize it. You could have your `Register` method take a `Delegate` and a `Type` instead of a generic method that requires an `Action<T>`.

Comment: You raise good points about the naming. Should do better even if it's just sample code. Just to note that the `RegisterHandlers` isn't declared wrong, it's not an extension method, it's just a static method. The static class is perhaps named misleadingly. It's too bad C# does not support free functions and forces one to put everything in a class.

The base class comes from a 3rd party library so I have no control over that. One option would be to subclass and place the method there but that forces the user to use that class as a base which is not optimal as C# has only single inheritance.